# UBUNTU 11.10 will not boot after succesfully installed on 8GB usb 3.0 pendrive

Tags: 11.10, boot, usb

UBUNTU 11.10 on 8GB USB 3.0 pendrive.
Drive Partitioned using gparted.
4GB BASE 3GB Home 600MB swap

Installation Ok. Restart blinking cursor.

Installed another distro on another USB 3.0 stick.

It boots OK.

--------------- DEBUG --------------------------------------

Boot Other distro and check:

I compare boot file with another linux.

grub of ubuntu is 1.4mb contend is different.

Taken photo with mobile camera but can not add here.

Files has note(music) sign on it.

Downloaded 11.10 desktop and Installed. Same result.

Will download 12.x when ready and try.

Ready to try any suggestion.

Comment: is there any error message associated with booting the ubuntu pendrive? also what kernel are you trying to boot if you even get far enough into the boot process to choose

Comment: Seen noMSG.wait several minutes  CTRL+ALT+DEL dont work

Answer (score 1):

If i were you, I would have downloaded the 12.04 LTS [Non-PAE core](http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/non-pae/), which will just work almost on any configuration.
After installation, you will get a terminal CLI, then you'll have all the possible option to get a complete desktop environment.

to install Ubuntu desktop

```
sudo apt-get update && dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get -y install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get check
sudo reboot
```

Please note that if you hav RAM more than 4 GB, then non-PAE version is "NOT SUGGESTED" to use.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add an option nolapic to boot ubuntu on my asus laptop.  Not sure if that's going to solve your problem, though.

In order to add that option, hit F6 during the boot time (not sure exact timing).  It will bring up a list of extra boot options, choose nolapic then follow instruction to continue boot.

If this works, you can edit /etc/default/grub to add this option to boot, and run sudo update-grub (or something similar).

Hope this helps.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

the best suggestion i can give you is, if you're willing , maybe try using ubuntu 12.04 beta [which direct link or torrents for the iso's can be found here](http://distrowatch.com/?newsid=07137/) which may fix your issue. or i would try the other answers or wait for the official release (april 28 i believe)

Answer (score 0):

This not an answer -- consider as my opinion :)

I was wondering why are you trying to install ubuntu in usb by creating separate partitions etc? It is much simple to create a live usb for booting. All your changes will be preserved , can boot to any other system also.

> If grub menu coming for live mode and if you have dual graphics card, choose "noapic" or "nolapic" after hitting F6 in GRUB menu.

Apart from that GRUB will be different on different distro, it has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: For myself I have USB3 hdd with Fuduntu. using it as MOBILE_PC